# Using quotes inside sageplot environment in SageTeX

Tags: graphics, sagetex

Here's the question: how do I get the following to work in SageTeX?  The quotes always lead to an error.

```
\sageplot{plot(cos(x),(x,0,pi),label='$\cos(x)$')}
```

Double quotes, escaping them, ... nothing seems to work.

Comment: if you press the sagetex tag and please submit a small description of what it does and can it would be nice. In that way people can read of what it actually does. I have no experience in it so have simply created the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough to tell you what's going on, but this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{sagesilent}
G=Graphics()
var('x')
G+=plot(cos(x),(x,0,pi),label='$\cos(x)$')
\end{sagesilent}
\[ \sageplot{G}\] 
\end{document}
```

Note, to get even more control over the placement of your text label try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{sagesilent}
G=Graphics()
H=Graphics()
var('x')
G+=plot(cos(x),(x,0,pi))
H+= text("$\cos(x)$", (3, 1), fontsize=16, color='black')
\end{sagesilent}
\[ \sageplot{G+H}\] 
\end{document}
```

The people at [AskSage](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/1304/using-quotes-inside-sageplot-environment-in) will know what's best. Here's output from the first set of code: [image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I *am* "one of the people at AskSage" :) so that's why I came here, thanks for pointing out that one can compute in a sagesilent and then just plot that.

Comment: I'm not worried about text placement, the real issue was the quotes not working.  There must be something wrong with the parser for sageplot.  Incidentally, you should be able to remove the whole extra `Graphics()` and `var` incantations and just directly do `G = plot...`, since `x` is predefined and all plots begin with empty graphics objects.

Comment: In that case, you might be interested in knowing that I didn't get an error when I processed the .sage file resulting from your sageplot using  Sage version 4.7. But when I ran LaTeX the second time I ended up getting a garbage label: instead of cos(x) it was $' on one line and oli and part of an "n" on the next line. Strange.

Comment: Mysteriouser and mysteriouser.  Because that means the real problem is in the TeXShop engine, maybe - I used `%!TEX TS-program = sage` and it was during the LaTeX stage that I had problems; it never actually got to Sage.  I assumed this was a SageTeX problem but apparently that was mistaken.

Comment: I tried TeXShop, Kile, LaTeXilla, Gummi, and TeXmaker and got the some output. When I tried highlighting the PDF where the garbage label was, a lot of text became visible (but crushed together); something like $\mathop{\mathgroup\symoperatorscos} and on the next line dimit. If a screenshot or the PDF file will be helpful in tracking down the problem, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the quotes that are the problem here. If you used `'cos(x)'`, it will work. The real problem is the dollar signs and the `\cos`: TeX is interpreting stuff before `\sageplot`. With the dollar signs, here's what ends up in your `.sagetex.sage` file:

`_st_.plot(0, format='notprovided', _p_=plot(cos(x),(x,0,pi),label='$\mathop {\mathgroup \symoperators cos}\nolimits (x)$'))`

In this case, SageTeX does exactly what you (unintentionally) asked: it includes the above text as a label. And since TeX does this before `\sageplot` sees anything, there's nothing SageTex can do.

The above solution with `sagesilent` is more complicated than necessary, but works because the dollar signs and backslashes inside `sagesilent` are passed directly to the `.sagetex.sage` file. Here's a simpler way:

```
\begin{sagesilent}
  P = plot(cos(x),(x,0,pi),label='$\cos(x)$')
\end{sagesilent}

\sageplot[width=.5\textwidth]{P}
```

Comment: I'm guessing your finals just ended, sir :) good to hear from the expert!